# Showing the most recent opened items in a menu bar

Tags: java, swing, menu

I want to create a window with Java Swing. The window will have a menu bar with a *File->Open* button from where the user can select a file from hid hard drive. The *File* menu should also have a list of the most recent opened items, like many other applications show. Does anyone know what is the best approach?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest using the [`Preferences`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html) class to persist the most recently opened items.  That way, if the user restarts the application the items will still be available.

Note that on Windows the `Preferences` class stores data in the registry, which is how many native Windows applications store and retrieve recently open file names.

Also, note that the Preferences class simply acts as an API for storing and retrieving (key, value) pairs.  You will still need to decide how you wish to store the information, and be responsible for dynamically building / updating the `JMenu` when a new file is accessed.  To accomplish this I would suggest implementing a `Action` (extend `AbstractAction`) to deal with when the user attempts to open a file.  When the `Action` runs it should persist the newly accessed file's name to the `Preferences` class and dynamically rebuild the File `JMenu` (in addition to opening the file).

Comment: +1 For `Preferences`, although it's not _just_ for Swing. As an aside, `Preferences` on Mac OS X are stored in individual files in `~/Library/Preferences`.

Comment: Good point - I've amended my answer.  I could have sworn Preferences was in the javax.swing package.